# Same random numbers in each run in Fortran

Tags: random, fortran

I have the below Fortran code:

```
program Looops
  implicit none 
  
  integer, parameter:: PPPP = 3.1415     
  real*8 , Dimension(:) , allocatable  ::dkk25,dkk26,dkk27,dkk28 
  integer:: n_38
  
  Allocate(dkk25(40))
  Allocate(dkk26(40))
  Allocate(dkk27(40))
  Allocate(dkk28(40))

  call RANDOM_NUMBER(dkk25)
  call RANDOM_NUMBER(dkk26)
  dkk27(:) = sqrt(-2*log((dkk25(:))))*cos(2*pppp*(dkk26(:)))

  do n_38 = 1 , 40
    dkk28(n_38) = ((dkk27(n_38)-(sum(dkk27)/40))**2)/(40-1)
  end do
  
  print*,dkk25
end program Looops
```

In each run of this code I have same value of `dkk25` and `dkk26`.
I want to generate different random number in each run.

Comment: Where is `RANDOM_NUMBER` defined?

Comment: it is pre defined by fortran

Answer (score 0):

Use `RANDOM_SEED` (with no arguments).

From https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/RANDOM_005fSEED.html :

> 8.225 RANDOM_SEED — Initialize a pseudo-random number sequence
>
> Description:
> Restarts or queries the state of the pseudorandom number generator used by RANDOM_NUMBER.
>
> If RANDOM_SEED is called without arguments, it is seeded with random data retrieved from the operating system.

Or use `RANDOM_INIT` if your compiler supports it.

Comment: please edit the code. random_seed is not defined.

Comment: @nimasahakie I do not understand your comment. `random_seed` is a standard intrinsic subroutine. We have many examples of its use on this site.

Comment: No, don't do that - the behavior is undefined in Fortran. Yes, some implementations have that behavior, but you can't depend on it. Fortran 2018 added `RANDOM_INIT` for just this purpose. `call RANDOM_INIT(REPEATABLE=.false.)`  gfortran now supports RANDOM_INIT.

Comment: One of the  examples I mentioned is at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65966220/random-number-generating-in-fortran `random_init()` is also shown there.